# Transparent background for constraint layout in android not working

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

> ***Transparent background for constraint layout in android not working***

I'm trying to make a custom android dialog with rounded corners.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLTjV.png)

As you can see, the corners are rounded, but it leaves the white corner still intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this in your dialogue activity

```
yourDialogName.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using **Fragment** that extends with *DialogFragment()*

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    requireDialog().window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.white_curve_with_blue_outline)//you can use here the drawable
    requireDialog().window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#BF303030")))//you can use here the color/Transparent


}
```